# Samsung Smart Tv SDK 5.1 App Development

Tags: javascript, html, css, samsung-smart-tv

Can anyone help me with making an app with the latest Samsung Smart Tv SDK 5.1? In the previous SDKs there was only one option of  Native Smart Tv App but there are so many options available in the latest SDK.

Options: 
Samsung Smart TV
1.Apps Framework 
 - Scene(AF 2.)
2.Caph
 - Page(Caph 1.0)
3.Native App
 - PNacl Module(C)
 - PNacl Module(C++)
 - PNacl Unit Test Project
 - Web + PNacl Module(C)
 - Web + PNacl Module(C++)
 - Web App with existing PNacl Module
4. Semantic Mashup
 - Semantic Mashup File

I need to play a live stream in my app. Which option should I choose? I am new to this SDK and desperately need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create app for Samsung 2014 and older (Orsay models) then you use in IDE "File -> New -> Project -> Samsung Smart TV -> Web App"
In this app you can use JavaScript + HTML + CSS + Samsung API

If you want to create app for Samsung 2015 and newer (Tizen Models) then you use in IDE
"File -> New -> Tizen Web Project -> Template Tab -> TV-2.4 (TV-2.3 for older 2015 models) -> Basic application"
In this app you can use JavaScript + HTML + CSS + Tizen API + Samsung Tizen API

I hope that it is helpful for you. If not do not hesitate to ask me :)